# R Shiny app not outputting location of the df specified by the user

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the following two sliderInputs on my R Shiny App

```
sliderInput("year", "Year:",
            min=2006, max=2016, value=2006),

sliderInput("month", "Month:",
            min = 1, max = 212, value = 1)
```

and I have a dataframe formatted like the following...

```
Month  2006  2007  2008
1      x1    y1    z1
2      x2    y2    z2
3      x3    y3    z3
4      x4    y4    z4
5      x5    y5    z5
```

What I am wanting to do is be able to show as an output on the app the value for the Month / Year selection. So for example I doing this...

```
df[4,c("2006")]
```

Doing the above would return x4, the value of row 4 (Month 4) in Column 2006. However When I try this in my server.R it doesn't output the value.

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

      output$calculated <- renderText({

        #giving names to the user inputs
        Year <- input$year
        Month <- input$month

        paste(df[Month,c("Year")])

      })

  }
)
```

How do I do this correctly so the selection of the user will output the correct value at that location in the df?

Comment: You are trying to retrieve the 2006th column of the data.frame, is it really that large? Does `df[4,"2006"]` work instead? (BTW: numbers are column or row names is often problematic, partly because of this, partly because when printed they do not include the quotes (`'` or `"`) needed to actually use them for indexing.)

Comment: My fault that was a typo on my bad. Yes if I just do df[4, "2006"] in a R script it returns x4, the value I want. But when I try to implement that to my Shiny app using the sliders don't return any value

Comment: Use `df[4,as.character(input$year)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issue arises because you are using what is commonly recognized as a numeric value type as a column name... so when it is passed to your filtering/subset action it throws an error. If you insist on having years as columns... you will need to coerce to a character, and for ease I showed using the `subset` function in the `server`

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  inputPanel(
    sliderInput("year", "Year:",
                min=2006, max=2016, value=2006, ticks = FALSE,step = 1, sep = NA),
    sliderInput("month", "Month:",
                min = 1, max = 12, value = 1)
  ),
  mainPanel(width = 12,
            column(6, htmltools::tags$h3('Original Data Frame'),
            tableOutput('original_d')),
           column(6,  style="padding-left:15%;",
                  htmltools::tags$h3('Filterted Result'),tableOutput('the_d'))
    )
)


# Helps to create bs data
fr <- function(nx = 1){
  l <- c('c','x','v')[sample(1:2, 1)]
  n <- sample(1:14, 1)
  v <- sprintf("%s%s", l, n)
  if(nx > 1){
    append(v, sapply(1:(length(v) - nx), fr))
  }else {
    v
  }
}

# Our index data.frame
var_df <- as.data.frame(
  append(list(1:12),
         lapply(1:11, function(i){
           fr(10)
           })
         )) %>%
  setNames(c('Month', as.character(2006:2016)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$original_d <- renderTable({
    var_df
  })
 output$the_d <- renderTable({
   subset(var_df, Month == input$month, as.character(input$year))
 })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: screenshot]